# как имитироать нажатие клавиши ENTER используя язык c++ и функцию keybd_event();

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

а как с помощью keybd_event('/n', 0, 0, 0); имитировать нажатие клавиши ENTER?
при использовании '/n' вместо нажатия ENTER получаю точку('.')(проверял в дискорде), а при исползовании '{ENTER}' возникает ошибка: E0026(microsoft visual studio comunity 2019) слишком много знаков в символьной константе
вот мой код:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    Sleep(10000);
    while (TRUE)
    {
        keybd_event('C', 0, 0, 0);
        keybd_event('C', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        //system("PAUSE");
        keybd_event('/n', 0, 0, 0);
        keybd_event('{ENTER}', 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        Sleep(3000);


    }
}
```

Comment: В документации указаны соответствующие значения для первого параметра

Answer (score 0):

'\n' - код символа переноса, а функция требует код клавиши.
Вам нужен VK_RETURN (или просто можете написать 0x0D)

См. [Virtual-Key Codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes)